# Spring Rest Docs - How to obtain simple HTTP GET from SpringMVC app

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

Am new to Spring Rest Docs... Have a preexisting codebase what was written in Spring MVC (not Spring Boot).

Some excerpts from my pom.xml looks as following:

```
<properties>
    <snippetsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets</snippetsDirectory>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Documentation.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-docs</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <backend>html</backend>
                        <doctype>book</doctype>
                        <sourceDocumentName>index.adoc</sourceDocumentName>
                        <attributes>
                            <snippets>${snippetsDirectory}</snippets>
                        </attributes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static/docs</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-docs</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Have a sample web service (using SpringMVC) which issues a simple GET request:

```
package com.myapp.rest.controllers;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v2")
public class MyController {

        @RequestMapping(value="users/{userId}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody Object getUserDetails(@PathVariable String userId){
            Object response=null;
            UserDAO dao = UserDAO.getInstance();
            response=dao.getUser(userId);
            return response;
        }
}
```

Calling this using curl:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8080/myapp/v2/users/123
```

Returns the following payload:

```
{
    "device": "D045453",
    "userId": "123",
    "userDetails": 
    [
        {
            "propertyName": "Position",
            "propertyValue": "Manager"
        },

        {
            "propertyName": "Salary",
            "propertyValue": "120000"
        },

        {
            "propertyName": "Name",
            "propertyValue": "John Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

Have setup my MockMvc test case like this:

```
WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:**/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class MyControllerDocumentation {

    private static final String USER_ID = "123";

    @Rule
    public final JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation)).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getUserDetails() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/v2/users/{userId}", USER_ID)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("device").isNotEmpty())
                    .andDo(document("{class-name}/{method-name}"));
    }
}
```

There's no applicationContext.xml anywhere just the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml (which resides in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.rest.controllers" />
       <mvc:annotation-driven />

       <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I start tomcat (because I already have a previous war file containing this rest call in $CATALINA_HOME/webapps) and when try to build the war file:

```
mvn clean install
```

This is what comes up in Surefire Reports:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.638 sec <<< FAILURE!
    getUserDetails(com.myapp.rest.controllers.MyControllerDocumentation)  Time elapsed: 0.2 sec  <<< FAILURE!
        java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
            at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
            at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
            at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:665)
            at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
            at om.myapp.rest.controllers.MyControllerDocumentation.getUserDetails(MyControllerDocumentation.java:49)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Question(s):

1. How can I obtain a simple HTTP 200 from my unit test? Is this a config issue?
2. Inside the:

   .andDo(document("{class-name}/{method-name}"));

How do I setup it to document the various properties (key / value pairs) located in the response JSON payload using Spring Rest Docs?

3. Am thinking that I do not need to have tomcat running (with a previous war file)?

Sorry, have never used Spring Rest Docs and just wishing someone could point me in the right direction...

Comment: I think you'd be better focussing on one problem at a time. To begin with, I'd take REST Docs out of the picture and just learn how to use MockMvc. You don't need Tomcat when you're using MockMvc. The 404 would suggest that your controller(s) haven't been found. It's not clear why that's the case without seeing more of your app and its configuration.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - Thank you for responding... Per your suggestion, I tried to setup a standard project using MockMvc and posted all the details (including configuration) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755487/mockmvc-to-test-springmvc-rest-web-service-using-junit-mockito-and-hamcrest Would appreciate it if you could assist me.