# MockMvc to test SpringMVC Rest Web Service using JUnit, Mockito, and Hamcrest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test, mockmvc

Am using Spring MVC to create Restful Web Services...

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>

        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    <import resource="classpath:database_db.xml" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.rest" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

src/main/resources/database_db.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <bean id="dataSourceDB"  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property>
        <property name="url"><value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</value></property>
        <property name="username"><value>root</value></property>
        <property name="password"><value></value></property>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

UserController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v2")
public class UserController {

    private final UserDAO dao;

    @Autowired 
    public UserController(UserDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "users/appId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Object getUserDetails(@PathVariable String appId) {
        Object response = null;
        response = dao.getUser(appId);
        return response;
    }
}
```

UserDAO:

@Repository
public class UserDAO {

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public UserDAO(@Qualifier("dataSourceDB") DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}   

// Various get and finder methods
```

}

src/test/java:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:**/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void appUser() throws Exception {
        String appId = "1234FD57";

        mockMvc.perform(get("/v2/users/{appId}", appId)
                       .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                       .andDo(print())
                       .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.myapp.rest.controllers.UserControllerTest

MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = GET
         Request URI = /v2/users/1234FD57
          Parameters = {}
             Headers = {Accept=[application/json]}

             Handler:
                Type = com.myapp.rest.controllers.UserController
              Method = public java.lang.Object com.myapp.rest.controllers.UserController.getUserDetails(java.lang.String)

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = null

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 200
       Error message = null
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.751 sec
```

The test runs but the body doesn't contain any JSON (notice how its blank)...

When I change the contents of my test method to:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/v2/users/{appId}",appId)
                   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                   .andExpect(status().isOk())
                   .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].userId", is("1234FD57")));
```

Received the following error:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.766 sec <<< FAILURE!

user(com.myapp.rest.controllers.UserControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.157 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myapp.rest.controllers.UserControllerTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.rest.controllers.UserController 
    com.myapp.rest.controllers.UserControllerTest.userController; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory
    NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myapp.rest.controllers.UserController] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.mockito.InjectMocks(), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties
```

Its just like in the print() statement showing nothing for "Body" no JSON... Am getting really close, does anyone know what I am off by?

Comment: Not sure why your request is being handled by the right handler, but your request mapping is missing `{}` around the path variable. It should be
`@RequestMapping(value = "users/{appId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)` What is `@ResponseBodyObject`? Should not it be `@ResponseBody`?

Comment: That was a typo - Edited it and its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with Spring 4.0.3 you have to use the old jsonpath 0.9.1, see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12299

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to 0.9.1 and now have a new error... Will update my post soon with the new error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are initialising your UserController in your test. You can either:

1. Initialise it in the test yourself. `UserController userController = new UserController();`
2. @Autowire the UserController. But you would also need to include the configuration with your component scan into the @ContextConfiguration

Comment: I just tried what you said... Just updated the post to show you what happened using your suggestion. Its giving me Bean wiring problem now.

Comment: Ah right yeah you would also need to add your configuration that does your component scanning to the @ContextConfiguration. Or you can just not autowire it and just do UserController userController = new UserController() in the test

Comment: The Autowire for the controller fails... What do I do after instantiating the UserController? Can you provide an example of component scanning to the @ContextConfiguration (what needs to be in there)?

Comment: After reading your code again I realise you actually are component scanning in your test since you're including mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml (which contains the component scan) in your context configuration for the test although for some reason it's not working. Can you tell me what package your UserController is under? If it's not under a branch of com.myapp.rest then you need to add this to the component scan. If it is then my only other suggestion would be to try @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml") instead of what you currently have.

Comment: Plog - Thanks for responding... My UserController is under com.myapp.rest.controllers. I made more progress (now it prints the Content-type and also I put it under headers). Since this post was forking in a different direction and I am after the JSON content please see this new post which has more details (config xmls, package names) thanks:             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793335/no-json-content-comes-up-null-from-mockmvc-test-using-spring-mvc-and-mockito

Comment: No problem. I have realised now what I was saying is wrong though. @InjectMocks annotation is enough to initialise the UserController. Sorry!